# Проблемы при настройке symfony 2.7 и 3.0 (проблема одна и та же)

Tags: php, framework, symfony2, symfony, symfony3

Проблемы при настройке symfony 2.7 и 3.0 (проблема одна и та же)

> Major problems have been detected and must be fixed before continuing:
>   Change the permissions of either "app/cache/" or "var/cache/"
>   directory so that the web server can write into it. Change the
>   permissions of either "app/logs/" or "var/logs/" directory so that the
>   web server can write into it.

Стандартные решения, естественно, попробовал из [документации Symfony, глава Checking Symfony Application Configuration and Setup](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#checking-symfony-application-configuration-and-setup).

**Setting up Permissions:**

```
Yuri@localhost /v/w/symfony.loc> sudo rm -rf var/cache/*
Yuri@localhost /v/w/symfony.loc> sudo rm -rf var/logs/*
Yuri@localhost /v/w/symfony.loc> sudo setfacl -R -m u:apache:rwX -m u:Yuri:rwX var/cache var/logs
Yuri@localhost /v/w/symfony.loc> sudo setfacl -dR -m u:apache:rwX -m u:Yuri:rwX var/cache var/logs
Yuri@localhost /v/w/symfony.loc> sudo service httpd restart
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart  httpd.service
```

Группа у web-server точно apache. Пруф

```
Yuri@localhost /v/w/symfony.loc> 
ps axo user,comm | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1
apache
Yuri@localhost /v/w/symfony.loc>
```

Так же использовал крайние решение из главы **Setting up Permissions**:
подставил в начало файлов: *(bin/console, web/app.php и web/app_dev.php)* -> umask(0000) в начало;

```
Yuri@localhost /v/w/symfony.loc> sudo service httpd restart
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart  httpd.service
Yuri@localhost /v/w/symfony.loc> service httpd status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  httpd.service
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Чт 2015-12-24 23:17:13 MSK; 11min ago
 Main PID: 9196 (httpd)
   Status: "Total requests: 8; Idle/Busy workers 100/0;Requests/sec: 0.0121; Bytes served/sec:  51 B/sec"
   CGroup: /system.slice/httpd.service
           ├─9196 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─9197 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─9198 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─9199 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─9201 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─9205 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─9207 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           └─9354 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND

дек 24 23:17:13 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP...
дек 24 23:17:13 localhost.localdomain httpd[9196]: AH00548: NameVirtualHos...
дек 24 23:17:13 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP ...
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
Yuri@localhost /v/w/symfony.loc>
```

Nginx и php-fpm точно не включен

```
Yuri@localhost /v/w/symfony.loc> sudo service php-fpm status
[sudo] пароль для Yuri: 
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  php-fpm.service
● php-fpm.service - The PHP FastCGI Process Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/php-fpm.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
Yuri@localhost /v/w/symfony.loc> sudo service nginx status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  nginx.service
● nginx.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)
Yuri@localhost /v/w/symfony.loc>
```

На просторах Ru&En-нета не нашел больше решений:(
Повторюсь, проблема на symfony 2.7 и 3.0 идентична. Пробовал на fedora 22 php5.6.15 и php7. Пробовал уже различные комбинации владельцев apache:Yuri, в том числе и на создание новых файлов тоже выставлять - ничего не помогло.:(
Есть еще возможные варианты?

Comment: Понятно, что проблема в том, что я ставлю все права как надо. Но после запуска bin/console cache:clear или web/config.php все права перезатираются, как были по дефолту. Umask(0000); я уже в console, app_dev, app, config.php проставил, как советуют в офф мануале, они не затираются, но и не работают. Уже пробовал и фреймворк через нового созданного юзвера с первичной группой apache ставить - проблема та же.

Comment: Юрий, я, конечно, понимаю, что у меня на русском SO мало репутации, чтобы править вопросы без проверки. Но посмотрите хотя бы статистику моих правок, мои правки на enSO. Я никогда не вношу правки, которые бы не улучшили вопрос. Перейти по якорю намного проще, чем искать на странице нужный раздел. Тега symfony3 (также как и symfony2) в сообществе Symfony принято избегать. Дайте сообществу делать вклад, не отклоняйте правки с надуманными "причинами".

Comment: Обсуждение правки этого вопроса на Мете: [Что делать, когда правку незаслуженно не принимают с одного лишь голоса автора](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/2219)

Comment: @YuriGlushenkov, а `composer update` делали? Проверку запускаете с консоли или через `config.php`?

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov: `composer update` делал. Через консоль все ok, через `config.php` (тоже `umask(0000);` на всякий случай в нем, как советуют в офф мануале для `app_dev.php` ets не помоголо) проверяю. 
Думал забить на `config.php` и продолжить работу, но уже ошибка о том что не возможно прочитать из `var/cache/dev/` (предварительно `dev` директорию в дефолтном состояние восстановил после `rm -rf var/cache/*` ).

Answer (score 1):

Если кому интересно, то проблема была в **SELinux**.
`vi /etc/selinux/config` или `nano /etc/selinux/config`
И перезагрузить комп `sudo reboot`

Answer (score 0):

я не парился и добавил алиас на composer который выполняется от www-data
sudo www-data -c 'composer app/console' вроде такого.